# how to create dynamic key and valuse in javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Input JSON

```
0===>{"eid":12,"gender":"1","age":1,"pass":["2","1"]}
1===>{"eid": 11,"gender":"0","age":1,"pass":["1","3"]}
2===>{"eid":20,"gender":"1","age":1,"pass":["2","3"]}
```

how to create new array.. to push the ids based on the pass numbers

Ex: IN a loop display

passid => 2  ....  eid => 12, 20

```
2 ==> ["12","20"]
1 ==> [12, 11]
3 ==> [11,20]
```

Comment: Makes no sense at all, and doesn't even look like valid JSON ?

Comment: please refer the ans from andy ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to check the contents of the `pass` array and then return the respective `eid` values:

```
function grabber(data, pass) {
    return data.filter(function (el) {
        return el.pass.some(function (num) {
            return +num === pass;
        })
    }).map(function (el) {
        return el.eid;
    });
}

grabber(data, 1); // [12, 11]
grabber(data, 2); // [12, 20]
grabber(data, 3); // [11, 20]
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dkbeqw3w/1/)

UPDATE

Realised on the way home from work you don't actually need `some`. Further, to answer your comment, here's how you might search for `pass` and `gender`:

```
function grabber(data, options) {
    return data.filter(function (el) {
        return el.pass.indexOf(options.pass) > -1 && el.gender === options.gender;
    }).map(function (el) {
        return el.eid;
    });
}

grabber(data, { gender: '0', pass: '1' }); // [11]
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dkbeqw3w/2/)

Comment: Thank you, .. here possible to filter with gender and pass id ?? grabber(data, 0, 1); // [ 11]